# Is it possible to load two instances of a jquery plugin, jQuery Facebook Multi Friend Selector on the same page?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using the jfmfs(jquery facebook multi friend selector) jquery plugin in a project and would like to know, if its possible to have two plugin instances of this running in the same page?

For example, this is how I created one instance and its working perfectly fine.

```
$("#jfmfs-container").jfmfs({ 
                          max_selected: 3, 
                      max_selected_message: "{0} of {1} selected",
                      friend_fields: "id,name,last_name",
                      sorter: function(a, b) {
                                    var x = a.last_name.toLowerCase();
                                    var y = b.last_name.toLowerCase();
                                    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
                      },
                                              labels: {
                                                selected: "Selected",
                                                filter_default: "Start typing a name",
                                                filter_title: "Find WinkMates:",
                                                all: "All",
                                                max_selected_message: "{0} of {1} selected"
                                                // message to display showing how many items are already selected like: "{0} of {1} chosen"
                                              }

                  });
```

If I try to use the same container in an another div or create a whole new container to load the second instance, it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Did you give the second container another ID? And then did you call the plugin on that second element?

Comment: Yes I did and also called the plugin on that second element. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a class and not an id, i use class instead of id in other jquery stuff and in this way i can load multiple instances. something like this:

```
$("#jfmfs-container").jfmfs({ 

                          max_selected: 3,
```

to

```
$(".jfmfs-container").jfmfs({ 
                          max_selected: 3,
```

in this way every container will use a diferent instance

Comment: I tried this,
`$(".jfmfs-container-1").jfmfs({ 
                          max_selected: 3,` and
`$(".jfmfs-container-2").jfmfs({ 
                          max_selected: 3,`

and then included the div like this,
`<div class="jfmfs-container-1"></div>` and
`<div class="jfmfs-container-2"></div>`
But it doesn't seem to work!